# Keyboard not responding as it should

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, keyboard-layout, thinkpad, screenshot

I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad T440p and all of a sudden my keyboard is no longer responding as it should. The top row keys function well, so does the Ctrl key when marking several folders at once. The S key now takes screenshots, which previously worked through pressing the print key on the buttom right. I have updated, as well as upgraded my OS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Lastly, I even fully reinstalled the OS, but it does not resolve the issue. The keyboard sometimes shortly works normally (which indicates it is a software issue), but after a few minutes goes back to the same issue. Using an external / USB keywork works fine. Solutions offered online such as switching off bounce and slow keys, or installing xserver-xorg-input-all do not work for me. Advice on what to do is highly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you may want to check that little ribbon that connects the keyboard to the motherboard isn’t coming loose. I’ve seen that numerous times over the years with “well-used” Lenovo ThinkPads that are over 10 years old 

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem unrelated to Ubuntu. Try booting from a live Ubuntu insulation USB using the **Try Ubuntu** option. If the keyboard does not work, it is broken.